# spring boot graphql app Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean'

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I am trying to implement graphql to my spring boot project. I added model.graphqls file under the /resources/graphql/ but my application is not starting and giving this error:

```
ERROR 17028 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/spring/web/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLHttpServlet' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/spring/web/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLHttpServlet' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletConfiguration' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/spring/web/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletConfiguration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'invocationInputFactory' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/spring/web/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'invocationInputFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/spring/web/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/tools/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/tools/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaClassScannerError: No Root resolvers for query type 'Query' found!  Provide one or more graphql.kickstart.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver to the builder.
o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     java.base@11.0.11/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
```

Here is my model.graphqls file:

```
type Player{
    id: String
    name: String
    surname: String
    position: String
}

type Query{
    getAllPlayer : [Player]
}


 type Mutation {
    createPlayer(name: String!, surname: String!,position: String!,): Player!
    deletePlayer(name: String!, surname: String!,position: String!,): Player!
}
```